# What does `lambda: class(class, class, ...)` syntax mean? (Twisted Python document)

Tags: python, lambda, twisted

I want to implement a Telnet Server using Twisted python. According to [Twisted documentation](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/95020403107ca2e57dc0addb5695357a/demo_recvline.tac), I wrote code below and it works correctly. but I have 2 problems with it.

First of all, I can not understand what `lambda` syntax exactly mean in this code and how those three classes are related to each other using lambda.

Second, I need to use `self.transport.getPeer()` to get client ip address. but there is nothing similar to `transport` attribute in `HistoricRecvLine` class. (`self.transport` is one of `ServerProtocol` attributes.)
I really need to use `recvline` in order to manage terminal, and also need to use `transport` attribute. But i don't know how to use both of them.
What do you recommend?

```
from twisted.application import internet
from twisted.conch import recvline
from twisted.conch.insults import insults
from twisted.conch.telnet import TelnetTransport, TelnetBootstrapProtocol
from twisted.internet import protocol

class DemoRecvLine(recvline.HistoricRecvLine):

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print(line)
        if line.decode() == "quit":
            self.terminal.loseConnection()
        self.terminal.write(line)
        self.terminal.nextLine()
        self.terminal.write(self.ps[self.pn])
        #print(self.transport.getPeer().host)

f = protocol.ServerFactory()
f.protocol = lambda: TelnetTransport(TelnetBootstrapProtocol,insults.ServerProtocol, DemoRecvLine)

PORT = 6023
from twisted.internet import reactor
reactor.listenTCP(PORT, f)
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can not understand what lambda syntax exactly mean in this code

It's defining a function with no name. It's as if you wrote

```
def noname():
    return TelnetTransport(TelnetBootstrapProtocol,insults.ServerProtocol, DemoRecvLine)

f.protocol = noname
```

i.e. a function that creates a `TelnetTransport` object with some parameters.

> how those three classes are related to each other using lambda

The `TelnetTransport` object will create some number of instances of each of those classes, presumably more than one.

Comment: Yes you are right. I checked `TelnetTransport`, `TelnetBootstrapProtocol`, `ServerProtocol`, and `HistoricRecvLine` classes and understand that the main class (`TelnetTransport`) gets some arguments in its constructor method. All of the classes in parenthesis are it's inputs and when the factory starts and a client connects to server a protocol and an instance of those classes are made.